# Массив заполняется не до конца\неверно

Tags: c++

Задача кода - вырезать из строки `main_string` символы с `A` по `B`, сдвинуть оставшуюся справа часть к части в начале строки, затем заполнить `main_string - result_string` символами `_`. "Вырезается" все замечательно, только вот дозаполнение символами `_` работает некорректно. Пример: Если `main_string` - последовательность от 1234567890, `A = 3`, `B = 8`, то результат должен выглядеть так: `123890___`, однако выглядит ответ так `123890_` (один символ _ ). Если кто сможет помочь или хотя бы навести на путь истинный, буду благодарен.
Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    char main_string[80], result_string[80];
    int a, b, counter = 0;

    std::cout << "enter the string" << std::endl;
    std::cin.getline(main_string, 80);
    std::cout << "you entered: \n" << main_string << std::endl;
    std::cout << "enter the number A" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "enter the number B" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> b;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(main_string); i++) {
        if (i < a || i > b - 2) {
            result_string[counter++] = main_string[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (strlen(main_string) - strlen(result_string)); i++) {
        result_string[strlen(result_string) + i] = '_';
    }

    std::cout << "result: " << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(result_string); i++) {
        std::cout << result_string[i];
    }
}
```

О попытках решения проблемы: пробовал смотреть, что происходит с `result_string` через breakpoint`ы. Итог был таким, что в какой-то момент массив просто перестает заполняться символом `_`, а именно после того, как заполнился один элемент).

Comment: заполнение `'_'` неправильно работает, потому-что вы длину строки ещё не можете узнать с помощью `strlen(result_string)` , так-как там нет в конце буквы с нулевым кодом `'\00'`. И даже после заполнения нулевую букву `'\00'` так туда и не поставили. *Нужно использовать переменную `counter` в замен.*

Comment: @AlexGlebe, спасибо за ответ. Еще два вопроса, если можно). Если после заполнения result_string в первый раз я добавлю нуль символ, смогу ли я потом дозаполнить его? Если нет, то нужно ли мне добавить этот символ после дозаполнения строки или он автоматически добавиться?

Comment: добавляется только одна буква, потому-что `strlen(result_string)` увеличился на единицу и переменная `i++` тоже. в промежутке находиться как раз нулевая буква `'\00'`. *Кажется в винде весь массив сначала заполнен ими.*

Comment: с массивом вы можете работать делать всё,что угодно. Добавлять нельзя, а менять буквы - можно.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, судя по инфе во время проверки по breakpointa`м массив каким-то шлаком заполнен. Там не только ```'\00'```

Comment: Извиняюсь за пинг, надеюсь, последний раз делаю это. @AlexGlebe, поправил все по вашим советам. Строка формируется как надо, но... Вместо ```127890____``` получается ```127890____\Z```. Откуда мог этот мусор взяться?.. Заранее спасибо, да и вообще огромное спасибо!

Comment: *добавьте* в свой вопрос эти изменения - посмотрим.

Comment: @AlexGlebe спасибо большое, со всем разобрался!